# Access to current AntiForgeryToken to HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, antiforgerytoken

Can I access to current `AntiForgeryToken` that generated in view to `HtmlHelper` extention method?

Something like this:

```
public static string AntiForgeryTokenValue(this HtmlHelper helper)
{

}
```

Comment: i can save AntiForgeryToken to ViewData"ViewData["AntiForgeryToken"] = Html.AntiForgeryToken();" and access in HtmlHelper.But,i am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get current anti forgery token value from incoming request... like below

MVC keeps this value in hidden form field with name __RequestVerificationToken...

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken`"]

You can also get in client side like below :-

```
$('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
```

(But why do you need its value in HtmlHelper while rendering view)

Comment: One reason you might want to access it, is that it's a handy guaranteed unique identifier for the form.  So if your form post adds database entities, you can use to prevent double submission from repeat clicks on the submit button and hence duplicate entities.